# Nuget Package Custom Visual Studio Destination Folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

This is an issue I am having with most js/css nuget packages but I'll use JQuery as an example here.

When I install the nuget package for JQuery, it installs the JQuery js file(s) into the "Scripts" folder in the solution.

I have a custom folder (~/Assets/Js) that I want them to go into for better organization.

Obviously I can drag them into that folder and rearrange them manually but its annoying having to do that every time I update or install a new nuget package.

Is there a way for me to specify a custom nuget destination folder for a package?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,

without changing the package before installing, you can't change that destination.

It's a choice made by the developer of the package.

If you want a wild idea for a solution, download the code for the Nugget manager and add custom code for

your development environment ( but this is overkill for your annoyance...)

JQuery is open source.

-->  Maybe propose a change to the guys who maintain JQuery...

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find any other "easy" solution either unfortunately. Just thought I would check and see if anyone else got around this somehow. Thanks again for the feedback :)